# Doctrine Query Builder query some columns in table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am using Doctrine 2, and I have a request to the database, in the first table(t1) I selected needed columns, and how to select some columns from a table(t2 and t3). 
I tried to do so, but I get an error. any idea?

```
addselect('partial t2.{id, name, description}')
addselect('partial t3.{id, name, description}')
```

my request

```
    $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
      ->getRepository('YourBundle:Entity')
      ->createQueryBuilder('t1')
      ->leftJoin('t1.table2', 't2')
      ->leftJoin('t1.table3', 't3')
      ->select('partial t1.{id, name, description}')
      **->addselect('t2, t3')**
      ->where('t1.name LIKE :q OR t1.description LIKE :q')
      ->setParameter('q', $test.'%')
      ->setMaxResults(16)
      ->getQuery()
      ->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error with **->addselect('t2, t3')**.  Do not use a single string.  Break up the string into arguments

```
->addSelect('t2')
->addSelect('t3')
```

Post any error message you receive.

Comment: George thanks, and how do I get specific columns of the table?

Comment: ->addSelect('t2') will get you the entire entity.  When you run the query, you can use the getter on $airports to get t2, then another getter for the field you want: $col1 = $airports->getT2()->getCol1();

Comment: this assumes that t2 is linked to your airport entity within the entity definition

Comment: you misunderstood me. I need to get from the database only specific columns in a table, in order to increase performance. 

->addSelect('t2') will get you the entire entity.
it's just I do not need, only some columns.

Comment: i'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: Ok, I think you can still do another add select and use partial.  Just stick with one additional table for testing.  Try ->addSelect('partial t2.{id, name, description}') and do not include any additional where statements.  You need to include the primary key in each partial.

Comment: FWIW, you may use `->addSelect('t2', 't3')`.

Comment: You may just do: `->addSelect('t2.field1, t2.field2, t3.field1, ...')`